# Unauthorized access to Google account after change of password, what now?

Tags: account-security, google

About a month ago, a friend got a security warning about some stranger signing into his Google account, so we changed his password to a strong randomly generated password with all characters (I think it was 20 characters long).

Today we got a new security warning about the same unknown account signing in again, what can we do to stop this intruder?

So far we haven't noticed this person doing anything with the account, which I find strange, but it might just be a matter of time.

Google refuses to be contacted in any way, as usual, absolutely worthless.

Comment: How do you know it is your friend? e.g. your friend's ISP sometimes assigning his home (or phone) a dynamic IP whcih Google geolocates at a different city

Comment: Was it a successful login or a login attempt?

Comment: Have you enabled MFA? If not, why not?

Comment: The "same unknown account" or the same IP? Is this IP very far from your friend's normal location? We really need more details here.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the same intruder, they are not covering their tracks very well. I guess you must be checking against IP addresses in the login history. What you can do is;

1. You should advise your friend to enable 2FA and reset the password.
2. Log out any unrecognised sessions in the security page.
3. Your friend should check if his device could have malware and take
   stages to remove such malware if that is a possibility.
4. If they write their passwords down, change where they are being stored.
5. Ensure any new password is unique and not shared across other sites.
6. Only use reputable VPNs or no VPN.

You can report it to the cyber-crime unit if there is one in your country.